# Unable to get the "Text" of the "element" using "Protractor"

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

Hi I am writing Protractor automation scripts for "Angular 4" application .

The development code is below.

```
<!--Byndd Title div-->
            <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-8 ui-lg-10">
                <div class="bynndTitleClass"  i18n="@@introductionBynddHeader">
                    BynddYour Information Together And CONNECT to the world  in an EFFICIENT way
                </div>
            </div>
```

my protractor test script is below.

Page Object code :

```
//to return login page heading 
    getLoginPageMainHeading(){
              return element(by.css('div[class="bynndTitleClass"]')).getText();
    }
```

Spec code :

```
 //Testcase1 : To open the "Login page" of the application 
    it('should open the Login page' , ()=>{
        //To open the Login page
        page.loginPageDisplay();

        // to verify whether the Current page is Login page or not by comparing with Login page Main heading
        expect(page.getLoginPageMainHeading().toString()).toBe('BynddYour Information Together And CONNECT to the world  in an EFFICIENT way');
    });
```

After execution it is displaying below error message.
W

```
1) should test certificate tab should open the Login page
  - Expected '[object Object]' to be 'BynddYour Information Together And CONNECT to the world  in an EFFICIENT way'.
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Because `expect()` resolves a promise itself, you're on the right path to `return element.getText()` within your pageObject.

However, because you added `.toString()`, your `expect` command now puts the element to String rather than resolving the promise.

I'd suggest to return just the element, and apply the `getText()` within your `expect` statement. It makes more sense and keeps your pageObject function better re-usable for other tests as well.

**So here my suggestion:**

PageObject (return just the element without `getText()`):

```
//to return login page heading 
getLoginPageMainHeading(){
          return element(by.css('div[class="bynndTitleClass"]'));
}
```

and Spec (`getText()` instead of `toString()`):

```
//Testcase1 : To open the "Login page" of the application 
it('should open the Login page' , ()=>{
    //To open the Login page
    page.loginPageDisplay();

    // to verify whether the Current page is Login page or not by comparing with Login page Main heading
    expect(page.getLoginPageMainHeading().getText()).toBe('BynddYour Information Together And CONNECT to the world  in an EFFICIENT way');
});
```

Comment: @Emst Zwingli thanks for your reply .
I changed to my Spec and Po file code but still it is displaying same error.

It resolve by using above code which is mentioned in the comment

Answer (score 0):

This solves my issue

```
page.getLoginPageMainHeading().getText().then(function(value){
            expect(value).toEqual('BynddYour Information Together And CONNECT to the world in an EFFICIENT way');
        })
```

Comment: You don't have to explicitly resolve promises when using it with jasmine expect. `expect(page.getLoginPageMainHeading().getText()).toEqual('BynddYour Information Together And CONNECT to the world in an EFFICIENT way')` should work!